# React + Express + Nodemailer: Can't render components and Nodemailer together

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I want to render my React app with client-side routing and I want to send a mail with Nodemailer. Since Nodemailer can't be used on the client-side I have to implement this on the Express server.
This is what the server looks like:

**express.js**

```
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build/index.html'))
})

router.get('/sendmail', (req, res) => {
transporter.sendMail(options, (error, info) => {
      if (error){
        console.log(error)
      }
      console.log('Message was send!')
    })
})
```

1) So this renders the React components but when I route to '/sendmail' a blank page is shown, the index.html gets rendered without js and no mail was sent.

2) If I delete the first line `router.use(express.static...` and route to '/sendmail' a mail gets sent but my app won't render.

Also I've tried the following:

```
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('path', req.path)

  if (req.path === '/sendmail') {
      transporter.sendMail(options, (error, info) => {
      if (error){
        console.log(error)
      }
      console.log('Message was send!')
    })
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build/index.html'))
  }
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: Do you want to do this in production or development mode ??

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of routes in express, they will be matched from top to bottom:

```
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

router.get('/sendmail', (req, res) => {
// this will be processed when you send a GET for /sendmail to your express server
....
}

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build/index.html'))
  // this will always match if the request is not /sendmail
})
```

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work.
It's like express.static takes control and router.get gets ignored.